# Retrieiving random number from Prolog file in FLEX/Prolog Project

Tags: random, prolog, lpa-flex

I am currently working on something in FLEX using LPA Win-Prolog.

I need to generate some random numbers, which is not possible using FLEX. According to one source I read, it's possible to create a prolog file inside the same project and use it the generate the random number and access it from the FLEX file. Apparently Ch.7 in [this document](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3avSGLmmLW4MMJ%3awww.lpa.co.uk/ftp/4900/flx_tut.pdf+flx+tut+pdf&hl=en&gl=uk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShfwm1zOGGr78tXb_PpI3X6pGQChnMLxcOORFJh94h8qly5PP_6V5Ac4H1JxMw2neNWFHA6CBm5RWkm2RnM0kBtSw0vFKeDEdRw68510kJEA6yGUoLyxGPILgcxBptXsTGk3sfF&sig=AHIEtbSO2yqm5uraPW1L3v0ERFgS5dIWcA) is supposed to illustrate how to do this but I still can't figure it out.

If anyone has any experience using Flex and prolog I'd really appreciate some help.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can literally write LPA-prolog within a flex file. For example:

```
action run;
 do flash('Im flex') and
 write('Well, im prolog!')
.
```